# Save an image on asp.net server

Tags: c#, asp.net, jpeg

I'm trying to save a piture recovered from a byte[] on the asp.net server. Here is my code :

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cli.LOGO, 0, cli.LOGO.Length);

            ms.Write(cli.LOGO, 0, cli.LOGO.Length);

            string thePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            string wholePath = thePath + "\\logo.jpg";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(wholePath, FileMode.Create);

            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            bw.Write(cli.LOGO);
            bw.Close();
```

Where cli.LOGO is a byte array. I'm just trying to save it as a .jpg image in my App_Data folder (or anything else of course) but... It's doing nothing. cli.LOGO is not empty, but the file is not created... Why so ? Is it the proper way to save an image ? Thanks !

Comment: Call `File.WriteAllBytes`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this which is a bit shorter than your code:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/logo.jpg");
File.WriteAllBytes("file", cli.LOGO);
```

Comment: I've try the following if (cli.LOGO != null)
            {
                string thePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
                string wholePath = thePath + "\\logo.jpg";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(wholePath, cli.LOGO);
            } But it's not working neighter... Not doing anything. Any idea how to debug ?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
 if (Request.Files["Photo"] != null)
            {
                string path = "/uploads/" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "_" + Request.Files["Photo"].FileName;
                Request.Files["Photo"].SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
                SP.PhotoPath = path;

                //The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the 
                //corresponding physical directory on the server.
            }
```